# Generic editable functions in C using void*

Tags: c, generics, memcpy, void-pointers

I fall in some problem.

I need to write some function like `memcpy(void*, const void*)`, which its signature should be:

```
void arrayCopy(void *dest, int dIndex, const void *src, int sIndex, int len)
```

I noticed that, in many implementation of `memcpy`, we cast void* to char*, but I think this is not the case of me, as the `arrayCopy` function needed to be used on arrays of many types including `structs`.

So, how can I accomplish this?

EDIT:
the source code might be something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void arrayCopy(void *, int, const void *, int, int, size_t);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int dest[10] = {1};
    int src [] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    arrayCopy(dest, 1, src, 0, 5, sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%i\n", dest[i]);

    return 0;
}

void arrayCopy(void *dest, int dIndex, const void *src, int sIndex, int len, size_t size)
{
    char *cdest = (char*) dest;
    const char *csrc = (char*) src;
    int i;

    len *= size;

    if (dest == src)
    {
        printf("Same array\n");
    }else
    {
        cdest += (dIndex * size);
        csrc += (sIndex * size);
        for (i=0; i<len; i++)
            *cdest++ = *csrc++;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"char * " is just a bunch bytes, everything in C is ultimately bytes - you can cast a pointer to any data structure to char* (you will also need to know the size in memory of the structure)

Comment: char* is ptr of the same size as int*, but *int_var takes 4 bytes while *char_var takes 1 byte (on 4byte systems)

Answer (score 2):

The function must have an  element-size info, eg:

```
void *arrayCopy(void *dest, size_t di,const void *src, size_t si, size_t num, size_t esize)
{
  char *cdest = (char*) dest;
  const char *csrc = (char*) src;
  return memcpy( &cdest[esize*di], &csrc[esize*si], esize*num );
}
...
arrayCopy(dest, 1, src, 0, 5, sizeof*src);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot work with objects of type `void`. The Standard doesn't allow that. So you need to cast the void away, and the best type to use is `unsigned char`. There's a guarantee by the Standard that `unsigned char` can access all bits of any other type representable in your system.